# How to use $split operator with aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I want to use **$split** operator on date field.

```
[{
 "status": true,
 "beaconData" :{
    "date" : "15/07/2017, 11:00",
    "charge" : 15,
 },
 {
 "status": true,
 "beaconData" :{
    "date" : "2/07/2017, 15:00",
    "charge" : 35,
 },
 {
 "status": true,
 "beaconData" :{
    "date" : "2/07/2017, 11:05",
    "charge" : 5,
 }]
```

I have used like this

> db.orders.aggregate( [ { $project:{data:{$split:["$beaconData.date", ", "] }, 'status':1 }}])

but error returns like

> "errmsg" : "exception: invalid operator '$split'",
>
> "code" : 15999,

Comment: [$split](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split/) operator is available from 3.4 version.

Comment: Is there any way to calculate total charge based on date like
[{'status': true,''beaconData':{'date':'2/07/2017', 'totalCharge':40}},
{'status': true,''beaconData':{'date':'15/07/2017', 'totalCharge':15}},

Answer (score 2):

```
//$split works in 3.4 u can use $substr in ur case if ur date is always in the same format you asked
 db.orders.aggregate(
       [
         {
           $project:
              {
                data: { $substr: [ "$beaconData.date", 0, 9 ] }
              }
          }
       ]
    )
```